# How to make str_ireplace same case

Tags: php, string

How to make str_ireplace same lowercase and uppercase.
example

```
 $letters = array('jonny', 'gennie');
 $fruit   = array('ponny', 'petty');
 $text    = 'JONNY love Gennie';
 $output  = str_ireplace($letters, $fruit, $text);
 echo $output;
```

so the actually output is :

> ponny love petty

but i want like this

> PONNY love Petty

how to do it? actually i just need it if first letter is uppercase or all letters are uppercase.

Comment: As a really ugly workaround, you could just use str_replace and list each value twice or if it is a lot of values duplicate the array right before the change appending a lower case and upper case version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using explicit hard coded values in your example, so the easiest is to use `str_replace` instead of `str_ireplace`, and just do a pass for both lowercase and uppercase string replacements. You can simply build the uppercase and sentence case arrays off the lower case array, and then you don't even need to do any work:

```
$find_lc = array('moo', 'cow', 'something');
$find_uc = array_map('str_to_upper', $array);
$find_sc = array_map('ucfirst', $array);
$searches = array($find_lc, $find_uc, $find_sc);

$replace_lc = array(...);
$replace_uc = array(...);
$replace_sc = array(...);
$replacements = array($replace_lc, $replace_uc, $replace_sc);

$converted = $input;
for($i=0; $i<count($searches); $i++) {
  $converted = str_replace($searches[$i], $replacements[$i], $converted);
}
```

And now it'll simply be correctly case-replaced. A little verbose perhaps, and you need hardcoded lists, but your question seemed pretty specific instead of asking about "any possible word" (in which case you'll need to use something like [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php))